# How to do a weighted sum for k-NN with multiple class?

Tags: machine-learning, knn

I have a lots of data points (x, y) and I'm trying to use k-NN to predict future y'.

If y has only two possible values, then I can treat y = +1 or -1.
Each time I have a input x', find the nearest k elements, and multiple their y with inverse of distance(x,x').
If the sum is greater than 0, then I will predict y'=+1, otherwise y'=-1

However, right know my y has 10 different possible values.
How do I do similiar weighted sum under this situation?

Answer (score 0):

You can keep different scores for each class that are always positive, with more positive being a stronger association.  Then just take the class max score.